# Launch ASP.NET REST API and Blazor WASM from WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

So my current project is a .NET 7 WPF application which runs on a piece of hardware.

In order for "others" to view parts of the application I want to implement a Blazor WASM application from the same application.
So this means that a WPF application should also host an ASP.NET core application, which will serve the Blazor WASM.

I cannot (easily) move the ASP.NET core application into its own exe, since they need to use the same parts of the memory and hardware.

Now what I have tried is the following:

- Create a new Blazor WASM application in the same solution, hosted by ASP.NET core
- Add a reference to the ASP.NET core project from my WPF application
- Start the server from there through a static class "WebServer"

The webserver looks like this:

```
public class WebServer : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private static WebServer? instance;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private WebApplication? theApp;

    public static WebServer Instance
    {
        get
        {
            instance ??= new WebServer();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Basic constructor, make sure to make it private, so that it cannot be abused
    /// </summary>
    private WebServer() { cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); }


    public async Task<bool> StartWebServer(string[] args, ViewModelManager viewModelManager)
    {
        if (theApp != null)return false ;

        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => viewModelManager.ViewMeasurement);

        theApp = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (theApp.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            theApp.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            theApp.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            theApp.UseHsts();
        }

        theApp.UseHttpsRedirection();

        theApp.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        theApp.UseStaticFiles();

        theApp.UseRouting();

        theApp.MapApiEndpoints();
        theApp.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

        await theApp.RunAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        return true;
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => theApp?.DisposeAsync() ?? ValueTask.CompletedTask;

    public async Task StopWebServer()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await (theApp?.StopAsync() ?? Task.CompletedTask);
    }
}
```

Now I can simply start the server from my WPF application by calling it like this:

```
Task.Run(async () => await WebView.Server.WebServer.Instance.StartWebServer(Array.Empty<string>(), viewModelManager));
```

Only problem is that it does not register any of the ASP environment variables.
So it currently starts on port 5000 and it does not serve the WASM at all.
Is there an easy way to start using this sort of implementation without needing to create a dump or something of the environment variables?

Comment: How and where do you set the environment variables?

Comment: @mm8 These environment variables are set automatically by the environment when launching the ASP.NET core application from Visual Studio.

Comment: But not when starting your WPF applicaition obviously. So how do you set them in this context?

Comment: @mm8 Yeah So that is my entire point :) I don't really want to set them myself, but what I could do is to create a sort of dump when running "normally" and set those variables using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` when launching the webserver.

Comment: Hi Foitn - Did you figure this one out? I am trying to do exactly the same thing pretty much.

Comment: @jdm555 Nope, still looking for a fix

Comment: @Foitn I think I might have it. It seems that you can publish (either from CLI or right clicking the SLN in VS) your Blazor WASM project, and then simply copy all the files from the published Blazor WASM's wwwroot into the wwwroot directory that your WebAPI server is using.